# How to modify normal two-functions-codes into class-using codes in python? (To submit in leetcode)

Tags: python, function, class

I'm solving the leetcode problem (num. 200, # of islands).
To get through this problem, I coded two functions without making 'class', which cannot be accepted in leetcode submission.

My code :

```
grid = [
  ["1", "0", "1"],
  ["1", "1", "0"],
  ["1", "1", "1"]]
]

def Loop(Graph):

  Loop.m, Loop.n = len(Graph), len(Graph[0])
  Loop.visited = [[False for i in range(Loop.n)] for j in range(Loop.m)]
  Loop.myStack = []
  Loop.islandCnt = 0
  


  for i in range(Loop.m):
  
    for j in range(Loop.n): # start from (0, 0), end at (m-1, n-1)

      if (Graph[i][j] == "1") and (Loop.visited[i][j] == False): # DFS only when the current space is a part of an island and an unvisited one
        Loop.islandCnt += 1 # increment the number of islands
        DFS(i, j)
  
  return Loop.islandCnt





def DFS(i, j): # for marking the explored land as "visited"
  
  shift = 0 # to be aware of whether possible adjacent land exists or not
  Loop.visited[i][j] = True
  Loop.myStack.append( (i, j) )
  

  adjacent = [(i, j-1), (i, j+1), (i-1, j), (i+1, j)] # 4 directions check : in order of - left, right, up, down
  for ele in adjacent: # if the land that 1) doesn't exceed index boundary 2) is land 3) is unvisited => shift
  
    if (0 <= ele[0] <= Loop.m - 1) and (0 <= ele[1] <= Loop.n - 1) and (Loop.visited[ele[0]][ele[1]] == False) and (grid[ele[0]][ele[1]] == '1'):

        shift = 1
        DFS(ele[0], ele[1])


   # if the land to go does not exist => pop the stack and trace back
  if shift == 0:

    Recent = Loop.myStack.pop()
    if len(Loop.myStack) == 0: # if no more land to go has left => terminate the recursion
      None

    else:
      Loop.myStack.pop()
      DFS(Recent[0], Recent[1])
 


output = Loop(grid)
output
```

This looks complicated, so I'll simplify the structure of my codes.

1st function : *Loop(Graph)* / This contains simple **for loops such that I run the 2nd function for each element in Input**(list). Also **defining some variables** whose values are gonna be changed in 2nd function.

2nd function : *DFS(i, j)* / Doing some DFSs so that **variable values pre-defined in 1st function are changed**.

But the leetcode needs me to use the following template:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def numIslands(self, grid):
        """
        :type grid: List[List[str]]
        :rtype: int
        """
```

So I tried this (I simplified the structure)

```py
class Solution(object):
    def Loop(Graph):
      blahblah

    def DFS(i, j):
      blahblah

    def numIslands(self, grid):
      
      return(Loop(grid))
```

But it didn't work.. Anyone would help me? I cannot deal with this problem but just wasting hours :((

Comment: Are you aware of how to call a `Class`.instance - the way the platform supposedly works?

Comment: Yes I think, Solution.numIslands(grid) is the way leetcode runs my code.